# How to capture the Key_tab event

Tags: python, pyqt4, keypress

i am trying to capture the key_tab event, but no luck. i realized that it only works if there are no other widgets so the cursor has no where to go only then can i get the event to return. here is a simplified code sample.

```
class MyCombo(QComboBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyCombo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditable(True)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress) and (event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab):
            print "tab pressed"
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            print "return pressed"
        else:
            QComboBox.keyPressEvent(self, event)

class Form_1(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.combo = MyCombo()
        self.line = QLineEdit()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form_1()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

if i comment out the following two lines

```
self.line = QLineEdit()
layout.addWidget(self.line)
```

then it works fine, because there is only one widget left on the form.

where am i going wrong?

Cheers, Joe

Comment: Is this problem specific to Key_tab, or does it affect other keys too?

Comment: i didn't try every key in the library, but as in my example code above i tried the key_return which works fine.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if this problem is specific to key_tab or if other keys are affected as well.

Comment: this problem is specific to key_tab

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Key_Tab press event is never passed to any handler but to the setFocus() so in order to intercept the Key_Tab event, we need to implement the event() method itself.
so here is the new code:

```
class MyCombo(QComboBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyCombo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditable(True)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            print "return pressed"
        else:
            QComboBox.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab:
            print "tab pressed"
            return False
        return QWidget.event(self, event)

class Form_1(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form_1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.combo = MyCombo()
        self.line = QLineEdit()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```